# How to sort a QTableView by a column?

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview

I am using the `QTableView` to display a QAbstractTableModel:

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QAbstractTableModel>
#include <QTableView>

class TestModel : public QAbstractTableModel
{
public:
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const
    {
        return 2;
    }
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const
    {
        return 2;
    }
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
    {
        switch (role)
        {
        case Qt::DisplayRole:
        {
            return 4 - index.row() + index.column();
        }
        }
        return QVariant();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QTableView table;
    TestModel model;
    table.setModel(&model);
    table.setSortingEnabled(true);
    table.sortByColumn(0, Qt::AscendingOrder);
    table.reset();
    table.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

[image: The displayed widget]

The problem is that the result is exactly the same when I use:

```
table.sortByColumn(0, Qt::AscendingOrder);
```

or

```
table.sortByColumn(0, Qt::DescendingOrder);
```

or

```
table.sortByColumn(1, Qt::AscendingOrder);
```

or

```
table.sortByColumn(1, Qt::DescendingOrder);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: for me its working fine as you described

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`QAbstractTableModel` provides an empty `sort()` implementation.

Try doing

```
TestModel model;
QSortFilterProxyModel proxyModel;
proxyModel.setSourceModel( &model );
table.setModel( &proxyModel );
```

Comment: Thank you! It works! But what was I doing wrong? Why does my code not work？I have read the documentation of both QTableView and QAbstractTableModel up and down, but did not find out why.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, the QTableView just calls the QAbstractTableModel's empty sort() function? It does not do any soting on its own?

Comment: Yes exactly. QSqlTableModel does have a sort implementation iirc, so sorting works there without a proxy model. However, as you are using an own model, you need a QSortFilterProxyModel which - as the name suggests - does have a sorting implementation as well.

Comment: QTableView just forwards the sort call to model()->sort(...)

Answer (score 5):

For those looking to do this in Python, this works for PySide6.

```
import sys
from PySide6.QtCore import QAbstractTableModel, Qt, QSortFilterProxyModel
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QTableView, QApplication

class TestModel(QAbstractTableModel):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def rowCount(self, index):
        return 2

    def columnCount(self, index):
        return 2

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return 4 - index.row() + index.column()


def main():
    a = QApplication(sys.argv)

    table = QTableView()
    model = TestModel()
    proxyModel = QSortFilterProxyModel()
    proxyModel.setSourceModel(model)
    table.setModel(proxyModel)
    table.setSortingEnabled(True)
    table.sortByColumn(0, Qt.AscendingOrder)
    table.reset()
    table.show()

    sys.exit(a.exec())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```